# How to show users the status of their sharing between my app and their social networks?

Tags: social-media, sharing, facebook-connect

I am running a social commerce platform where customers can easily sign up via Facebook Connect. Products get shared via Twitter, Google+, Tumblr etc. All in all very convenient and of course, common standard.

Unfortunately it is not so common that you can also easily logout or at least see all an overview of all the social media channels you have opened on the platform. Since I would like to improve the user settings on that part I am looking for pros and cons.

**How should I design controls where you can see if you are still logged in or connected via Facebook Connect etc. or not?**

Comment: Your question is too broad and unclear. What problem *specifically* are you trying to solve?

Comment: Can you specify your question? What do you need to solve? Which part of your UI are you having trouble with? "Social media settings" is very broad and vague.

Comment: Basically I am just talking about an overview of all the connections, where you can see if you are still logged-in/connected via Facebook Connect etc. or not.

Answer (score 2):

You could just show a simple table with explanations of the state of these social tools and options to change their state.

By the way, this is something I haven't seen in action yet, but may be a real benefit to the user: Show how much is shared on average daily/weekly/monthly (depending on how frequent: for example > 10 per week = show daily average).

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fS7ePx.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Joe! Visualize personal sharing statistics could offer an interesting new perspective.

But, coming back to my initial question… The main reasons why we need to use that social media connections are:
a) Sign-Up/Sign-In
b) Share
c) Additional information (i.e. social addressbook)

Let's say we list it like your proposal. If you are not connected, you will see a 'Connect' button. My issue is, that this button usually gets hidden, once you enabled that connection.

I need to understand the reason for that. Otherwise I cannot explain it crystal clearly to my customers ;)

Comment: How to do this is more a programming question, I could only find a legacy function that facebook offers to log out: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/oldjavascript/FB.Connect.logout/

Answer (score 0):

Do your users explicitly share things via those other networks, or is it all passive?  If it takes an explicit action (like the FB/G+/Twitter links on StackExchange), then one way to indicate status would be to gray out icons/inks/menu items/whatever that aren't currently available (you can't share if you're not logged in).

Comment: It is explicit. Interesting way to visualize the status of a channel. Thanks for this!